# Usability patterns catalog

Tags: usability, design-patterns

While reading a revision history here at stackoverflow I noticed **a great usability pattern**: [a list of revision entries](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1577/list).

I like this approach since it is both easy to use and easy to implement. Now I'm wondering about a catalog of usability patterns for web applications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I really really like the [UI Patterns](http://ui-patterns.com/) site. It has lots of patterns, such as Input Feedback, Vote to Promote, *et cetera*, supported by screenshots of sites that are using them. You should definitely take a look at it.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

[Welie.com](http://welie.com/) is another user interaction pattern library, although many of its examples are starting to look/feel a little dated.  Maybe it's more useful as a Wayback Machine of design patterns? :-)